# Improve overall layout on ListView of Rows

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to implement a ListView of Rows like this:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:good_driver_app/common/ExpandedButton.dart';

class ServicePetrolPage extends StatefulWidget {
//  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

//  final String title;

  @override
  _ServicePetrolPage createState() => _ServicePetrolPage();
}

class _ServicePetrolPage extends State<ServicePetrolPage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text('Petrol'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Location",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Distance",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Facilities",
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 1",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Johnson Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "0.2 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.45",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "ATM, Restaurant",
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 2",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Hennessy Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "0.5 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.88",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "ATM",
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 3",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Lockhart Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "1.2 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.88",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Toilet",
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 4",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Canal Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "1.2 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.90",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Restaurant, Toilet",
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to put horizontal gap between cells?
2. How to reduce the gap between rows?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it.

**ServicePetrolPage**

```dart
class ServicePetrolPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ServicePetrolPage createState() => _ServicePetrolPage();
}

class _ServicePetrolPage extends State<ServicePetrolPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Petrol'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DataView(
              distance: 'Distance',
              facilities: ['Facilities'],
              location: 'Location',
              logo: ' Logo ',
              price: '',
            ),
            DataView(
              logo: 'Logo 1',
              location: 'Johnson Rd',
              distance: '0.2 KM',
              facilities: ['ATM', 'Restaurant'],
              price: '12.45',
            ),
            DataView(
              logo: 'Logo 2',
              location: 'Hennessy Rd',
              distance: '0.5 KM',
              facilities: ['ATM'],
              price: '12.88',
            ),
            DataView(
              logo: 'Logo 3',
              location: 'Lockhart Rd',
              distance: '1.5 KM',
              facilities: ['Toilet'],
              price: '12.88',
            ),
            DataView(
              logo: 'Logo 4',
              location: 'Canal Rd',
              distance: '1.2 KM',
              facilities: ['Restaurant', 'Toilet'],
              price: '12.90',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**DataView**

```dart
class DataView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String logo;
  final String location;
  final String distance;
  final String price;
  final List<String> facilities;

  DataView({
    this.location,
    this.distance,
    this.facilities,
    this.logo,
    this.price,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("$logo"),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Center(child: Text("$location")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(child: Text("$distance")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(child: Text("\$$price")),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (facilities != null)
                  ...facilities.map((facility) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '$facility ',
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Since I am using List unwrapping syntax you will have to update your
>   SDK constraints in pubspec.yaml
>
> **pubspec.yaml**
>
> ```
> .
> .
> environment:
>   sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

1- Add a `Container` and set the `height` to 1 with a color you want (between each container row).

```
  Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
```

2- Reduce the padding, I will change this `padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)` to this `padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2)`

Final code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text('Petrol'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Location",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Distance",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Facilities",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 1",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Johnson Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "0.2 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.45",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "ATM, Restaurant",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 2",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Hennessy Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "0.5 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.88",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "ATM",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 3",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Lockhart Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "1.2 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.88",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Toilet",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Logo 4",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Canal Rd",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "1.2 KM",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "\$12.90",
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: new Text(
                              "Restaurant, Toilet",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```